# How to to read data from text file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read data from text file 
I tried but it showing errors 
showing error at the path of the file

```
string txtfile = File.ReadAllText("D:\Temp\textdata.txt");
string txtdata = File.ReadAllText("D:\Temp\textstrings.txt");
string txtpara = File.ReadAllText("D:\Temp\textlines.txt");

Console.WriteLine(txtfile);
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine(txtpara);
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine(txtdata);
```

My file is saved in `d:\temp\textdata.txt`

Can anyone tell me ?

Comment: You need to say what the error is in order for people to help you...

Comment: The problem is with the backslash.. it is not allowing you to read the file with that path.. either u use "D:\\Temp\\Textlines.txt" means '\\' intead of '\'. or use @"D:\temp\textdata.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string value = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\temp\textdata.txt");

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Note the '`@`', this is an escape character for the extra back slash in your path.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is backslash symbol in your string containing filename. Sequence of characters `\t` means tabulation symbol.

You should either prepend your string with `@` sign like

```
@"D:\Temp\textdata.txt"
```

or use double slashes like

```
"D:\\Temp\\textdata.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me